# problem to show values in select option tage

Tags: html, angular

I have a select option tag to show female and male.
If I init options tag by static values, it works but if I use `ngFor` it doesn't show any values:

component.ts:

```
export class MemberListComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  userParams: any = {};
  genderList: [
    { value: "male"; display: "Males" },
    { value: "female"; display: "Females" }
  ];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userParams.gender = this.user.gender === "female" ? "male" : "female";
  }
}
```

and this is template:

```
<div class="form-group px-2">
    <label for="gender">Show: </label>
    <select class="form-control ml-1" style="width: 130px" id="gender" [(ngModel)]= "userParams.gender" name="gender">
    <option *ngFor= "let gender of genderList" [value] = "gender.value">
      {{gender.display}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is ngIf ? Where did u try? how did you  try ?

Comment: `this.userParams.gender = this.user.gender === "female" ? "male" : "female";` :O

Comment: @pc_coder I think he wanted to say `ngFor` instead of `ngIf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your declaration of the `genderList`. Instead of initializing the variable, you only declare its type and the value is `null`. Change the `:` to a `=` sign. Then typscript will also start to complain about your `;` inside the json object.

```
genderList: [
  { value: "male"; display: "Males" },
  { value: "female"; display: "Females" }
];
```

should be

```
genderList = [
  { value: "male", display: "Males" },
  { value: "female", display: "Females" }
];
```

or

```
genderList: User[] = [
  { value: "male", display: "Males" },
  { value: "female", display: "Females" }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this code?

```
<div class="form-group px-2">
    <label for="gender">Show: </label>
    <select class="form-control ml-1" style="width: 130px" id="gender" [(ngModel)]= "userParams.gender" name="gender">
    <option *ngFor= "let gender of genderList" [value] = "gender.value" [selected]="gender.value==userParams.gender">
      {{gender.display}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
genderList: [
    { value: "male"; display: "Males" },
    { value: "female"; display: "Females" }
  ];
```

You did not initialised the gender list correctly
You need to define it like

```
genderList:User[any] = [
  { value: "male"; display: "Males" },
  { value: "female"; display: "Females" }
];
```